# Facebook page inside android app

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to open a facebook business page inside my android app without the login. I know how to redirect to the facebook app instaleed on the device but that's not what I want. I want the page to open inside the app. Also, the webview solution goes to the login page first
How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the page. If the page is public, you can open it in a webview directly without logging in. otherwise you need to login.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! One more thing, the "setWebViewClient" has to be enabled otherwise it redirects to the browser.